# Ayuda sobre proyecto de programacion en python

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib

Buenas dias a todos, hoy les traigo una pregunta bien particular. Resulta que debo realizar un proyecto en Python 2.7 en el cual se me pide diseñar poliedros regulares (especificamente cubos) . No busco que me enseñen el código a desarrollar, sino que mas bien, me puedan ayudar con ideas sobre el algoritmo que podría utilizar para el desarrollo del proyecto, ya que por más que busqué informacion en libros e internet, no encontré casi nada.

Según los requisitos y limitaciones que se me entregaron en la clase, probablemente será un programa que me tomará mucho tiempo en realizar, a continuación les detallaré los requisitos que se me piden:

En este proyecto, los poliedros se deben representar en matrices de dos dimensiones de numeros enteros. Cada celda de la matriz tiene un numero entero N que representa un paralelepipedo de 1 x 1 x N . Por ejemplo, una matriz de 2x2 con todas sus celdas con valor 2 representa un poliedro de lado 2. Sin embargo, si uno de los valores de esa misma matriz es 1, entonces el poliedro resultante es ese mismo cubo pero con una de sus esquinas cortadas.

**Entrada del programa:** Un archivo de texto que contiene la matriz que representa al poliedro. Cada fila del archivo representa una fila de la matriz. Los valores de cada columna están separados por comas.
[image: Detalles de la entrada del programa]

**Salida del programa:** Debe mostrar por pantalla: la matriz, la vista ortogonal
del poliedro y el número de caras de dicho poliedro.

Vuelvo a repetir, no busco que me entreguen los códigos exactos que debo utilizar en el programa, ya que quiero valerme por mi mismo para crear las lineas de codigo del programa; sólo necesito información de como abordar el algoritmo, por ejemplo: por donde debería empezar, qué librerías debería utilizar y etc...

Aquí les dejo una imagen en donde se muestra lo que debería entregar por pantalla mi programa, de antemano, muchisimas gracias por su ayuda [image: Detalles de la salida del programa]

Comment: Esto es mas facil de lo que crees. Considera cada figura completa como un conjunto de x *unidades minimas*, siendo cada unidad mínima un *minicubo*; en cada matrix, un valor `1` indica que **no hay unidad mínima en esa posición**, mientras que otro valor indica que si, y su posición relativa. Busca sobre [Vóxel](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/V%C3%B3xel).

Comment: Me veo en la obligación de votar para cerrarla, pero que conste que el tema me gusta.

Comment: Gracias, al buscar por Voxel me has resumido bastante en el cómo debería afrontar el programa. Pero necesito algunos detalles adicionales como por ejemplo qué librería ideal debería utilizar para diseñar los "cubos" 3D. Por otro lado, quisiera saber la razon de por qué se me cerrará la pregunta :(

Comment: de lo demás, ni idea: no se python :-( . Lo de cerrar quiere decir que no admite mas respuesta hasta que no *cumplas* con lo mínimo; en tu caso concreto, son varios: la comunidad tiene un *protocolo* para preguntas correctas: mostrar lo que llevas hecho, el punto exacto del prolema, mas de una opinion como respuesta válida ... pásate por [la ayuda](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help), en concreto [que no preguntar](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: ahh perfecto, acabo de leer las reglas y efectivamente estoy rompiéndolas. Voy a diseñar otra pregunta, mucho más corta y especifica, para evitar ambigüedades y respuestas subjetivas. Saludos y muchas gracias por la ayuda y la aclaracion

Comment: Un placer, y encantado de tenerte por aquí. Cuantos mas seamos, mas aprendemos :-) y mejor lo pasamos :-))

Comment: Se me olvidaba. Ya tienes 20 puntos; ya puedes pasarte por [el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=es.stackoverflow.com); alli te pueden orientar mejor sobre como preguntar; las preguntas *sobre ejercicios* tienen que mostrar el código realizado hasta el momento, para evitar que esto se convierta en *el rincón del vago*.